# why caption is not centered under figure when using forest? How to correct

Tags: floats, captions, forest

I am following an answer in [How to include caption in \begin{forest}...\end{forest} in LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411984/how-to-include-caption-in-beginforest-endforest-in-latex)  where it shows how to put forest inside figure with caption, under the part where it says

> If you want a caption, switch to article and put the tree in a figure.

But when I try it on my code, in TL 2022, the caption is not exactly in the center. It seems to be shifted to the left. Here is a MWE and screen shot

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{caption}%do I need this?

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering   
\fbox{\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20,
    minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=2cm,
    align=center, base=b,
    s sep=1cm, l sep=.5cm,
    if level<=2{edge=-latex}{edge=red},
}
[differential\\equation
    [first Order 
     ,calign=last
        [first order\\degree not One,
           [{\small goto\\figure 2}, circle,draw,fill=yellow!20, minimum width=1cm]
        ]
        [first order\\degree one, 
            [{\small goto\\figure 1}, circle,draw,fill=yellow!20, minimum width=1cm]
        ]
    ]
    [second order, calign=first
        [linear]
        [nonlinear]
    ]
    [higher order, fit=band]
]
\end{forest}}
\caption{Main flow chart for solving an ode}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using lualatex gives this

[image]

Is the above the correct way to put forest inside figure with frame with caption? How to make caption be centered? I am using `\centering`.

ps. I used `\fbox` to put frame around the figure. Not sure if this is the best way or not but it seems to work.

Comment: And yuo did notice that your forest figure is wider than the text width? Try adding `\rule{\textwidth}{4mm}` inside the figure but outside the forest. Caption centers against the width of the text, it does not know the size of what ever there is else in the float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @daleif, you have a warning:

```
lilla.tex|35 warning| Overfull \hbox (84.20647pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 35--36
```

...and 84 points is quite a bit. I suggest using `\overfullrule=5pt` before `\begin{document}` always when editing a new document, which makes this kind of problem quite evident:

[image]

Comment: You mean people more likely to look at the pdf output than the log? Shocking!